# How do I find the InstanceID in an ova to set an IP Address when using ovftool to deploy to an ESXI 5.5. server

Tags: vmware, esxi, vmware-server, ovf

I found the following post which explained using the ovftool command line utility to set an IP address: https://www.mylesgray.com/virtualisation/deploying-ovaovf-remote-vcenter-using-ovftool/

My problem is that when I run the ovftool against the ova (and the ovf inside), I do not get the output I need to determine the Instance ID for the network adapater. The only Instance ID that comes up is for the disk, which doesn't work.

```
[root@delphi OVA_Build]# ovftool SSMS-2.1.3-Stage-root-unlocked.ova
OVF version:   1.0
VirtualApp:    false
Name:          SSMS2.1.3-Prod-OVF

Download Size:  2.68 GB

Deployment Sizes:
  Flat disks:   200.00 GB
  Sparse disks: 6.79 GB

Networks:
  Name:        VM Network
  Description: The VM Network network

Virtual Machines:
  Name:               SSMS2.1.3-Prod-OVF
  Operating System:   centos64guest
  Virtual Hardware:
    Families:         vmx-07 
    Number of CPUs:   4
    Cores per socket: 1
    Memory:           4.00 GB

    Disks:
      Index:          0
      Instance ID:    8
      Capacity:       200.00 GB
      Disk Types:     SCSI-lsilogic 

    NICs:
      Adapter Type:   PCNet32
      Connection:     VM Network
```

I'm trying to run the following command (using env variables $VERSION, $BUILD_NUMBER, and $BUILD_IP_ADDRESS) but I do not know what goes in the InstanceID slot. Alternately, I would be ok with a command that keeps the existing IP address, but right now the networking info (IP, Gateway, Netmask) are all getting cleared out.

```
ovftool \
-ds=Skywalker \
-n=SSMS-$VERSION-Stage-$BUILD_NUMBER \
--ipAllocationPolicy=fixedPolicy \
--prop:vami.netmask0.<InstanceID>=255.255.255.0\
--prop:vami.gateway0.<InstanceID>=172.18.77.1\
--prop:vami.ip0.<InstanceID>=$BUILD_IP_ADDRESS\
--prop:vami.DNS.<InstanceID>=64.102.6.247\
--powerOn \
SSMS-2.1.3-Stage-root-unlocked.ova \
vi://root:rootpass@dlo-vcenter-rtp.cisco.com/Corona/host/RTP
```